# Differences with predict.coxph vs predict when making predictions from a coxph object in R

Tags: r, predict, cox-regression

during package development I have come across peculiarities with the '*[predict.coxph](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/survival/html/predict.coxph.html)*' function from the survival package in R. It appears '*predict.coxph*' is not exported from the survival package, and that to call it I must use '*survival:::predict.coxph*' (note the triple ':::'). I have been using '*[predict](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/predict)*' from the stats package instead of '*predict.coxph*' for a long time, and this has made me think about the implications of both.

The '*predict*' function from stats must work out that the object is an coxph object and therefore generate the appropriate linear predictor, but there is no mention of using '*predict.coxph*' on the documentation page for '*predict*'.

**Question 1), how does it do this? Does it somehow find '*predict.coxph*' from the survival package, or is it completely seperate?**

The '*predict.coxph*' is not exported from the survival package, which seems odd, given it would be used widely.

**Question 2) why is predict.coxph not exported? Is it a bad idea to use '*survival:::predict.coxph'*?**

This is of interest because when developing a package reliant on '*predict.coxph*', I get a warning message about the use of ':::', so plan to use '*predict*' instead, but would like to fully understand how it works.

Reproducible code below. Note that coxph.pred1 and coxph.pred4 give the same answers, coxph.pred2 and coxph.pred3 cannot find the function.

```
library(survival)

### Load data
myeloma <- myeloma

### Add predictor
myeloma$x1 <- rnorm(nrow(myeloma), 0, 1)

### Fit cox proportional hazards
coxph.obj <- coxph(Surv(futime, death) ~ x1, data = myeloma)

### Check model output
summary(coxph.obj)

### Create predictions for individuals in myeloma dataset
coxph.pred1 <- predict(coxph.obj, type = "lp")
coxph.pred2 <- predict.coxph(coxph.obj, type = "lp")
```

Error in predict.coxph(coxph.obj, type = "lp") :could not find function "predict.coxph"

```
coxph.pred3 <- survival::predict.coxph(coxph.obj, type = "lp")
```

Error: 'predict.coxph' is not an exported object from 'namespace:survival'

```
coxph.pred4 <- survival:::predict.coxph(coxph.obj, type = "lp")

### Print how many elements are not the same in coxph.pred1 and coxph.pred4
sum(coxph.pred1 != coxph.pred4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `predict` function is generic.

```
predict
# function (object, ...) 
# UseMethod("predict")
# <bytecode: 0x13c66f4c8>
# <environment: namespace:stats>
```

you can tell that because it calls `UseMethod` which triggers S3 dispatching in R. This means that `predict` will call different functions depending on the `class()` of the object you pass to it. These functions are all called `predict.<classname>`. You can see all the different types of `predict` function with `methods(predict)`

By convention, packages that provide methods for `predict` to not export the "raw" `predict.<classname>` functions. Instead they register them as S3 methods. (See [here](https://github.com/therneau/survival/blob/3c6387f6daad85601edc174d08d16e706112c24e/NAMESPACE#L143) in the survival NAMESPACE file.) So you are meant to call just the `predict()` function with an object of class "coxph" and R will call `predict.coxph` for you. You should not use `:::` form of functions. Just use

```
coxph.pred1 <- predict(coxph.obj, type = "lp")
```

Comment: Thank you, that has filled a big piece of the jigsaw in for me, makes total sense.